# How to add many codecs.open to ' for ' loop

Tags: python

I need these lines to go in ' for ' loop to shorten the whole module.

```
peanut = codecs.open("butter.txt", mode="w")
duck = codecs.open("tape.txt", mode="w")
hair = codecs.open("style.txt", mode="w")
italy = codecs.open("spaghetti.txt", mode="w")
smile = codecs.open("cheese.txt", mode="w")
```

Something like:

```
for five_txt in peanut, duck, hair, italy, smile:
    codecs.open()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inst_dict = {}
for file in [('butter.txt', 'peanut'), ('tape.txt', 'duck'), ('style.txt', 'hair'), ('spaghetti.txt', 'italy'), ('cheese.txt','style')]:
    inst_dict[file[1]] = codecs.open(file[0], mode='w')
```

You can now also access the instances from the dictionary like:

```
inst_dict['peanut']
inst_dict['duck']
....
```

Comment: Calling the dictionary `dict` is a bad idea, because this hides the builtin constructor/type.

Comment: I just modified your suggestion and found out that it creates those files with 3 seconds faster, sorry about that delay I went sleeping and did not tried your suggestions till now. Many thanks to others who participated my thread and posted different solutions to my issue. Thank you Ankur Ankan and everyone else ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Put the filenames into a list and iterate through it.

```
filenames = ["butter.txt", 
    "tape.txt", 
    "style.txt", 
    "spaghetti.txt", 
    "cheese.txt"]

for fname in filenames:
    fhandler = codecs.open(fname, mode="w")
```

Comment: Thank you Shashank Gupta

Answer (score 1):

```
a_list = [peanut, duck, hair, italy, smile]
for elem in a_list:
    opened_file = codecs.open(elem, mode="w")
```

Comment: Thank you juankysmith, can I mark both of your comments with green sign ?